# similarities through whole Neo4j graph

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

i'm trying to get the similarities between one node say me and all the people in the graph not just "friend of friend" which uses the nth order relationship. do i have to go through the whole graph and looping through every user or there's a better way to go?

```
 MATCH (me { name: 'Bradley' })-[:INTEREST]->(stuff)<-
[:INTEREST]-(another_user)
RETURN another_user.name, count(stuff)
ORDER BY count(stuff) DESC
```

in brief how to replace `another_user` with all `users` in the graph in a clean and not costing way

Comment: What's the number of total in your graph? Getting a similarity between one node and all other nodes will costly unless you skip those nodes which doesn't have a common interest.

Comment: for an nth-order relationship, the cost depends on the connectedness of the graph. If the graph is highly connected the cost will be quite high.

Comment: the number now it low but with time it's going big but i have to do it because the whole app idea is to get the similarities between users who have the most common interests. is there another way to reduce the number without depending on the nth order ?  when i get that isn't it the default to skip nodes which doesn't have common interests?

Comment: i need to get most users similar to the user which i'm querying about

Comment: I think your query is sufficient to find similar users to Bradley. If you consider nth-level for example if we go one level deep in the above query additional users will have common interests with `another_user` and not with the Bradley.

Comment: Isn't is giving you what is expected?

Comment: @54ba The above query will not give the correct count as it is not an aggregating query but it will only show the nodes which have at least one node in common. To get the count of actual common nodes you will have to collect and then filter the nodes.

Comment: yeah that's what i meant Deepam. thank you guys for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should help you:

```
match (me { name: 'Bradley' })-[:INTEREST]-(stuff) with stuff, collect(stuff) as stuffs match (another_user)-[:INTEREST]-(common_stuff) where common_stuff in stuffs return another_user.name,count(common_stuff) ORDER BY count(common_stuff) DESC
```

This query will first collect all the items that Bradley is interested in and then iterate through other users and count the items which are common interests between them and Bradley.

Comment: Variable `n` not defined. should it be count(common_stuff) ?